# VBNet. Conversion Operators cannot Convert To Object. How Can I Restrict Conversions to Object?

Tags: vb.net, generics

Currently I lot of code spent converting Strings into numbers and checking that those numbers are valid.  So I'm trying to create a class to simplify this.

I created two Widening CType Operators to simplify assigning the class to either the number Type or a string. But I've run into a problem. When adding the Constrained number to a collection of objects, these CType operators are not called so the actual ConstrainedNumber object is added to the collection. Obviously the database does not support custom types like this.  VBNet will not allow me to create a CType operator for when the class is cast to an Object.

What I need is some way to cause a compiler error or warning if it is being cast to an object. Is there an Annotation that could specify this?  Or better yet, a way to override the CType Operator so I can convert to an object?

Here's the code:

```
    Friend Class ConstainedNumber(Of TNum As Structure)
        Private Property _number As Object
        Private Property _nDefaultValue As TNum
        Private ReadOnly _nMax As Double
        Private ReadOnly _nMin As Double
        Private ReadOnly _bCanEqualMin As Boolean
        Private ReadOnly _bCanEqualMax As Boolean

        Public Function IsValid() As Boolean
            Return IsValid(_number)
        End Function

        Private Function IsValid(value As Object) As Boolean
            Return isValidNumber(value, _nMax, _nMin, _bCanEqualMax, _bCanEqualMin)
        End Function

        Public Property num As TNum
            Get
                Return If(IsValid, CType(_number, TNum), _nDefaultValue)
            End Get
            Set(value As TNum)
                If IsValid(value) Then
                    _number = value
                End If
            End Set
        End Property
        Public Property str As String
            Get
                Return If(IsValid, _number.ToString, String.Empty)
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                If IsValid(value) Then
                    _number = Decimal.Parse(value)
                End If
            End Set
        End Property
        Public WriteOnly Property Val As Object
            Set(value As Object)
                If isValidObject(value) Then
                    str = value.ToString
                End If
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Sub New(defaultValue As TNum, nMax As Double, nMin As Double, Optional bCanEqualMax As Boolean = False, Optional bCanEqualMin As Boolean = False)
            _nMax = nMax
            _nMin = nMin
            _bCanEqualMax = bCanEqualMax
            _bCanEqualMin = bCanEqualMin
            _nDefaultValue = defaultValue
            num = defaultValue
        End Sub

        Public Function ToString() as String
            Return str
        End Function

        Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal value As ConstainedNumber(Of TNum)) As TNum
            Return value.num
        End Operator

        Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal value As ConstainedNumber(Of TNum)) As String
            Return value.ToString()
        End Operator

        '//Here is the Issue.  This CANNOT be done apparently. 
        Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal value As ConstainedNumber(Of TNum)) As Object
            Return value.num
        End Operator        

    End Class
```

Here is a usage Example

```
    Friend Class BasicSearchParams
        Public Property sKeyword As String = String.Empty
        Public ReadOnly dblLatitude As New ConstainedNumber(Of Double)(NoValueDouble, 90, -90, True, True)
        Public ReadOnly dblLongitude As New ConstainedNumber(Of Double)(NoValueDouble, 180, -180, True, True)
        Public ReadOnly dblPriceFrom As New ConstainedNumber(Of Double)(0, Double.MaxValue, 0)
        Public ReadOnly dblPriceTo As New ConstainedNumber(Of Double)(0, Double.MaxValue, 0)
        Public ReadOnly nListingsPerPage As New ConstainedNumber(Of Short)(1, 10000, 0) With {.Val = cGlobals.DefaultListingsPerPage}
        Public ReadOnly nPictureWidth As New ConstainedNumber(Of Integer)(0, Short.MaxValue, 0)
        Public ReadOnly nPictureHeight As New ConstainedNumber(Of Integer)(0, Short.MaxValue, 0)
    End Class
```

Another goal I originally had, but it doesn't appear to be possible, is to have "num" be a default property without having a Parameter. I tried the annotation below but it doesn't work.

```
<System.Reflection.DefaultMember("num")>
```

Comment: You have created an [inner-platform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect), or nearly so.  There are several ways to simplify what you have and avoid boxing a) use something like PostSharp to implement range validation b) Use part of the NET range validation but write your own validator.  In the case of (B) rather than implement your class `As T` perhaps use generics (`Of T...As T`) in the internal validation.  Even that way, the code gets more complex than it needs to be for such a simple task (it *is* tempting though).

Comment: I was not aware of the NET range validation RangeAttribute class.  That seems perfect.  

Postsharp also seems really nice.  But looks to require licensing and all developers to have it.

Comment: Range just holds/sets the valid range for a property; you need something else to do the validating. NET has one but it seems a bit limited IMO (and is meant for the Web). You can write your own easy enough, but simply constraining a value doesnt even need all that.  I am curious about all these string and object conversions. Whats the need to pass String and Object to what is essentially a numeric type, and then have the ability to convert back to String and Object?  How is that useful?