# How does one set a range of possible values a property can be in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net

I need a property to *never* be less than 0. **Is there a way to set a property's range so that it can never be a certain value, or in this case, never less than zero?**

I've looked into this, but since I'm not sure what I'm looking for, it's hard to do research.

Comment: Does it have to be a variable?  Can it be a property on a class?

Comment: @JamesThorpe No, it doesn't have to be. For my program, it's already a property. I was trying to ask the question in a generalized manner. It would still be helpful to know how to do this to a variable as well, just for knowledge's sake.

Comment: The two are quite different, and using properties allows you to do exactly what you're after - using a variable doesn't really generalise the question

Comment: @JamesThorpe Well, then, assume I meant to use a property. Apologies. My question still stands.

Comment: You should probably [edit] your question so that people can answer the right question rather than the wrong one :)

Comment: In that **specific** case you could consider using an UInteger but maybe validating data (in a setter property) would be better (and more general)

Comment: @JamesThorpe Is that your way of telling me you don't know the answer? :)

Comment: Is what my way of telling what?  I do know the answer and was part way through writing one but work got in the way - it's a pretty basic way of using properties

Comment: you could use a ConstrainedValue Type (a bit overkill) or use a method for a variable `Return If (var <0, 0, newValue)`  For a property, just use the setter

Comment: @Plutonix stupid question ... Is ConstrainedValue type a .Net thing ? I can't seem to find info on it. And you can replace your `If` with `Math.Max(0, newValue)` ;)

Comment: No, it is something you might write with code in place to constrain a value to a range (eg `Dim myInt As New ConstrainedValue(of Int32)(1, 9)`  where 1 and 9 are the Min and Max  @Sehnsucht

Comment: @Sehnsucht here is a [pretty bad example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30677631/1070452) of one

Comment: @Plutonix yeah I see what you mean now ; the initial wording make me doubt (I thought I missed that type)

Answer (score 2):

Raise an argument exception if the value is invalid.

```
Public Property MyProperty As Integer
    Get
        Return _myProperty
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        If value < 0 Then
            Throw New ArgumentException("Value must be greater than or equal to zero.", "MyProperty")
        End If
        _myProperty = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Alternatively, the property setter might be able to handle the out-of-range value. For example, if we don't what get raise the exception but instead use an alternate value within an acceptable range. Example:

```
Public Property MyProperty As Integer
    Get
        Return _myProperty
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        If value < 0 Then
            _myProperty = 0
        Else
            _myProperty = value
        End If
    End Set
End Property
```